# Как исправить ошибку "TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable"

Tags: python, python-3.x

Мне необходимо написать программу, которая открывает файл, считывает данные и производит над ними операции.

При отладке появилась ошибка:

> "TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable".

Не могу понять с чем она связана и как ее решить.

Сама ошибка представлена на скриншоте

https://i.stack.imgur.com/NuFwt.png

### Код программы:

```
class File(): # в классе происходит обработка данных из файла и необходимые для работы вычисления
    def __init__(self):
        print('в классе') 

    def FILE(self):#построчное чтение из файла
        self.y = []
        self.t1 =[]
        self.t2 =[]
        self.x = []
        self.y1 = []
        self.input_file = easygui.fileopenbox(filetypes=["*.docx"])
        self.f = open (self.input_file)
        nenado = '---end of log file---'
        for i in range (2):
            self.f.readline()
        for line  in self.f:
            if nenado in line:
                break
            else:    
                a = line[1:6]
                b = line[7:12]
                time = line[25:32]
                self.t1.append(float(a))
                self.t2.append(float(b))
                self.x.append(float(time))        
        self.f.close()

    def rasschet_ΔTy(self):#график из файла
        self.y = [self.t2 - self.t1 for self.t1, self.t2 in zip(self.t1, self.t2)]
        return self.y

    def rasschet_x(self):#ось времени
        self.x = [z/60 for z in self.x]
        return self.x

    def rasschet_ΔTy1(self):# график смещенный в 0 
        self.k = self.t2[0] - self.t1[0]
        self.rasschet_ΔTy()
        self.y1 =[g - self.k for g in self.y]
        return self.y1

    def rasschet_filtr_ΔTy(self):# цифровой фильтр для графика из файла
        self.yhat = savgol_filter(self.rasschet_ΔTy(), 251, 3)
        return self.yhat

    def rasschet_filtr_ΔTy1(self):# цифровой фильтр для графика смещенного в 0
        self.yhat1 = savgol_filter(self.rasschet_ΔTy1(), 251, 3)
        return self.yhat1

a = File()

def demo():
    a.FILE()
demo()

def Demo():#для проверки
    print(a.rasschet_ΔTy1())
    print(a.rasschet_ΔTy())
    print(a.rasschet_x())
Demo()
```

---

Comment: Пожалуйста, не добавляйте код и/или ошибки в виде скриншотов. Неудобно читать, невозможно копировать. Добавьте текстом в вопрос (кнопка [edit])

Comment: Меня смущает тут кое что: `self.y = [self.t2 - self.t1 for self.t1, self.t2 in zip(self.t1, self.t2)]`. Вы итерируете по `self.t1` и `self.t2` и значения записываете в них же. Я бы переписал место как:  `self.y = [t2 - t1 for t1, t2 in zip(self.t1, self.t2)]`

Comment: она связана с той строчкой, которая указана в тексте ошибки. Смысл, вроде бы, тоже должен быть понятен - нельзя итерироваться по числу.

Answer (score 1):

Если убрать всё лишнее, то можно смоделировать вашу ситуацию таким примером:

```
class Example:
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = [3.14, 4.15]
    
    def func(self):
        self.b = sum(self.a for self.a in self.a)
        #   тут будет проблема  ^^^^^^ 

example = Example()
print(example.a)
example.func()
print(example.a)
example.func()
```

Вывод:

```
[3.14, 4.15]
4.15
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-17-5a56c598e878> in <module>()
     10 example.func()
     11 print(example.a)
---> 12 example.func()

<ipython-input-17-5a56c598e878> in func(self)
      4 
      5     def func(self):
----> 6         self.b = sum(self.a for self.a in self.a)
      7 
      8 example = Example()

TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable
```

Из-за того, что вы использовали поле класса в качестве переменной для спискового сокращения, это поле перестало содержать список и стало содержать последнее из значений списка. Метод класса, который вызывает проблемную функцию у вас тоже вызывается два раза. Первый раз он отрабатывает нормально, а второй раз уже "обламывается".

Эта проблемная строка у вас, как уже заметил **gil9red** в комментариях:

```
self.y = [self.t2 - self.t1 for self.t1, self.t2 in zip(self.t1, self.t2)]
                                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Не используйте поля класса в качестве временных переменных спискового сокращения, используйте там какие-то обычные переменные и проблем не будет.

Comment: Исправил, как вы сказали и все заработало! Спасибо большое за ваш совет!